# Partially Parsing XML File Without XMLParser in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, parsing, file-io, xml-parsing

so I found out it was possible to use the buffered reader/writer to copy an xml file over word for word to a new xml file. However, I was wondering if it would be possible to scrape out only a portion of the document?

For example, looking at this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookCatalogue xmlns="http://www.publishing.org">
    <w:pStyle w:val="TOAHeading" />
    <Book>
    <Title>Yogasana Vijnana: the Science of Yoga</Title>
    <author>Dhirendra Brahmachari</Author>
    <Date>1966</Date>
    <ISBN>81-40-34319-4</ISBN>
    <Publisher>Dhirendra Yoga Publications</Publisher>
    <Cost currency="INR">11.50</Cost>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>The First and Last Freedom</Title>
    <v:imagedata r:id="rId7" o:title="" croptop="10523f" cropbottom="11721f" /> 
    <Author>J. Krishnamurti</Author>
    <Date>1954</Date>
    <ISBN>0-06-064831-7</ISBN>
    <Publisher>Harper &amp; Row</Publisher>
    <Cost currency="USD">2.95</Cost>
  </Book>
<w:pStyle w:val="TOAHeading2" />
</BookCatalogue>
```

Sorry if this is not proper XML Code, I just added the tidbits from the document I was looking at to this sample I found. But basically, if I wanted to look for the an instance of "heading" (in this case, 3rd line -> TOAHeading), then scrape everything from heading down until another instance of heading is found and copy it to another xml file. Is that possible? Furthermore, if I wanted to make that a temporary file I'm storing to, and only keep that file if an instance of "image" (in this case, 14th line) is found, is that possible as well? I'm trying to do this in the simplest way possible, so does anyone have any ideas or experience with this? Thanks in advance.

```
public class IPDriver 
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStreamReader("C:/Documents and Settings/user/workspace/Intern Project/Proposals/Converted Proposals/Extracted Items/ProposalOne/word/document.xml"), "UTF-8"));
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamReader(new FileOutputStreamReader("C:/Documents and Settings/user/workspace/Intern Project/Proposals/Converted Proposals/Extracted Items/ProposalOne/word/tempdocument.xml"), "UTF-8"));

                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    writer.write(line);
                }

                // Close to unlock.
                reader.close();
                // Close to unlock and flush to disk.
                writer.close();
            }
        }
```

**Example From My Actual XML Document**

```
- <w:smartTag w:uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" w:element="address">
- <w:smartTag w:uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" w:element="Street">
- <w:r w:rsidRPr="00822244">
  <w:t>6841 Benjamin Franklin Drive</w:t> 
  </w:r>
  </w:smartTag>
  </w:smartTag>
  </w:p>
- <w:p w:rsidR="00B41602" w:rsidRPr="00822244" w:rsidRDefault="00B41602" w:rsidP="007C3A42">
- <w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="Address" /> 
  </w:pPr>
- <w:smartTag w:uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" w:element="City">
- <w:smartTag w:uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" w:element="place">
```

Just your basic document.xml file from a .docx

Comment: @maasg nope. working on a project (for work), this only a part of the larger project, but im fairly new to working with xml

Comment: I personally, would use a xmlparser library (e.g. dom4j) but if you have this requirement, why don't you scan the file line by line and check whether each line contains the word "heading". If yes you start writing the next lines until you find another line which contains "heading". In the meantime you can also check if some line contains "<v:imagedata>". As soon you come to a second "heading" you store or delete the temp file based on your results. However, this is kind of a naive implementation and as I said, it will be better to use a xml library for number of reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a lot of technically-correct suggestions, but your request (when taken as-written) suggests to me that you have the following requirements:

- Start parsing at a case-insensitive (and potentially PARTIAL) matching of an **attribute value**; in your case you wanted to match "heading" to the second half of "TAOHeading".
- Parse from that odd starting condition down to a matching (and equally odd) ending condition.

If I understood your requirements, you are basically wanting to do a totally unstructured parse of a very structured piece of data (XML markup). In that case, using an XML parser, an XSLT, DOM parser for anything written against the XML spec is going to be a pain in the ass to mangle to your needs.

You'll need to do a case-insensitive scan of your document contents until you get your match, then pull all the characters between that match and an ending match.

If the documents aren't huge (say 1 MB or smaller) just read the whole thing into memory into a String and either use a really quick and dirty use of "indexOf" for the different cased versions of what you want, OR read the whole thing into a char[] do write some more efficient scanning code for a case-insensitive match for the starting value you want to begin parsing at.

If I misunderstood your requirement and it is actually much more structured than it sounded in your description above, then please use one of the other suggestions that is more focused on true XML parsing. I am just putting this solution out there in the off chance that it was as random as you made it out to seem.

(NOTE: I'm not saying it's BAD, just never seen that request before. You have your own reasons for needing to do that and we'll just try and help ;)

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to read about java XML Parsers. There are two types, SAX parsers and DOM parsers.

SAX parsers are 'event based', meaning that the parser will scan over the xml file for you and call a set of 'callback' methods that you have defined, such as startElement() and endElement(). SAX parsers are efficient for very large xml files.

DOM parsers will read the entire XML into memory and then you can just query the 'DOM object' by calling methods like getElementsByTagName("w:pStyle"). Dom parsers tend to be a bit easier to work with, but use more memory than SAX parsers.

There will be a bit of a learning curve, but these are the standard ways of processing XML in java. There are also libraries designed to simplify the standard libraries, such as JDom.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are sure that your XML looks like this**, you can simply compare each line with `<w:pStyle w:val="TOAHeading" />`, and then start outputting the following lines, until you find a line which matches `<w:pStyle w:val="TOAHeading2" />`.

But why would you do this? It is fragile to any formatting changes. **Use an XML Parser (and a XML writer), it makes the life much easier**.

Comment: what if it is minified and there are no line breaks? There are XML parsers for a reason, use them.

Comment: See the reason I was thinking about reading this line-by-line (without a parser) was so that I could identify an instance of image between heading and heading, THEN scrape out the section or even scrape out the section between heading and heading to a temp file, identify if an instance of image exists, if not then discard, else.... Then I was would use the SAX parser to find the attributes I was looking for in the newly created XML document.

Does that seem a good way about it, or largely inefficient? Because from what I know, you can't read back up using a XML parser, right?

Comment: @Jarrod: Yes, I wrote this, too. Maybe I should add some emphasis to my answer.

Comment: @This: This would be a reason to use a DOM-like API instead of SAX. See the answer from James.

Comment: @Jarrod - his request is odd enough (wanting to parse from a case-insensitive attribute VALUE down to another one) that using an XML parser for this would big a pain in the ass, since what he is doing isn't XML parsing... it's an odd duck.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this would be to use an [XSLT](http://www.google.com/search?q=xslt) transform that emitted everything but what you don't want. This is just what XSLT is mean to do.

Don't parse this by hand it will lead to failure, definitely don't even think of using regular expressions that will lead to epic failure.

If you can't comprehend XLST, and it is a paradigm shift from procedural coding, ask for help here, or fall back on using a traditional XML parsing library for your use case you are going to probably have to use some `DOM` based parser, I prefer [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson I will look into XSLT, but for the other part of this project where I used XML parsing I was working with SAX (primarily because the xml documents I'm working with do not have a well-defined tree-structure...hence why I avoided DOM). So do you think there is a feasible solution here with SAX?

Comment: Does *do not have a well-defined tree-structure* mean that they are not well-formed (i.e. the opening and closing tags do not nest correctly), or that there is no type definition or schema?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann It means the former (it is not nested correctly). I included some sample code in the original post.

Comment: @This: It looks nested fine (assuming there is a `<w:p>` tag before the excerpt you posted, and the two tags in the last two lines are closed later). (It is not indented, but XML does not need to.) A SAX-parser should not accept non-wellformed XML, either. (And if something is not well-formed, it is not XML, only an XML-like language. I think docx is real XML.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Hmm, interesting. Someone I spoke with (who I thought was pretty knowledgeable on the subject) said the structure looked strange to them, so that's what I based my assumption on. However, even with the use of DOM, it can only read down, so if I wanted to identify an instance of "image" and scrap everything above it...that wouldn't be possible, correct?

Comment: @This: I'm not really an XML guru, but I think most SAX implementations would not allow backtracking. You can simply throw away the information you don't need, though.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, So you think it would be possible to do something with SAX where I'd basically parse through, write everything between two headings out to a new xml file, parse through with SAX again, identify an instance of image in the new file (save if found, trash if not). Then parse through a third time to look for the target attributes?

Comment: @This your example is well formed, all the tags are nested and closed correctly. The XML spec does **NOT** require ordering of attributes **OR** elements to be significant. In practice most XML parsers deliver the elements in the order they are discovered, but this isn't required by any spec. Well formed means the nesting isn't interleaved and all tags are closed correctly. Look up XML Lint.

Comment: @Jarrod I was thinking about using DOM for this phase of my project? Do you think that would be a good way to go? And I looked at XMLLint, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for?